# Construct Google+ Post Permalink Given UserID and ActivityID

Tags: google-api, google-plus, permalinks

I am using the Google+ API V1: https://developers.google.com/+/api/

I am trying to programatically build a permalink to a given G+ post given a `userId` and an `activityId`.

I can make the following GET request to the API URL:
https://www.googleapis.com/plus/v1/activities/z12rwbngzpbzi1i2q23qizvavtaiixfy104?key={YOUR_API_KEY}
where `z12rwbngzpbzi1i2q23qizvavtaiixfy104` is the `activityId`.

And I get back the following response:

```
{
 "kind": "plus#activity",
 "etag": "\"RqKWnRU4WW46-6W3rWhLR9iFZQM/NFwidT-LJOR8oitQXt0iVc0TQwk\"",
 "title": "Best. Nade. Ever.",
 "published": "2014-05-15T01:13:22.496Z",
 "updated": "2014-05-15T01:13:22.496Z",
 "id": "z12rwbngzpbzi1i2q23qizvavtaiixfy104",
 "url": "https://plus.google.com/116428676193009789012/posts/FTcMCiju5ux",
 "actor": {
  ...
 },
 "verb": "post",
 "object": {
  ...
 },
 "provider": {
  ...
 },
 "access": {
  ...
 }
}
```

You see the response JSON includes an `id` field which is the `activityId` as well as a `url` field which I am trying to construct without needing to make an API call. The URL is in the form `https://plus.google.com/{USER_ID}/posts/{UNKNOWN_ID}` so `"116428676193009789012"` is my G+ `userId`.

I have tried to use different URL formats to see if any combination will work, even if it just redirects me to the actual URL. All of the following formats result in a `404` response:

- `https://plus.google.com/{USER_ID}/{ACTIVITY_ID}`
- `https://plus.google.com/{USER_ID}/posts/{ACTIVITY_ID}`
- `https://plus.google.com/{ACTIVITY_ID}`
- `https://plus.google.com/u/0/{USER_ID}/{ACTIVITY_ID}`
- `https://plus.google.com/u/0/{USER_ID}/posts/{ACTIVITY_ID}`

How can I construct a valid Google Plus Post URL (permalink) given a `userId` & `activityId`?
Is it even possible?

Comment: This is possible for Facebook with the format `http://www.facebook.com/permalink.php?story_fbid={POST_ID}&id={PROFILE_ID}`. It is also possible for Twitter using the format `https://twitter.com/{USERNAME}/status/{TWEET_ID}`. I hope G+ has something similar.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use activityId to link to the mobile interface but it will look terrible on desktops. For desktops there is no choice but to query the API.

https://plus.google.com/app/basic/stream/z12rwbngzpbzi1i2q23qizvavtaiixfy104

Comment: I was not aware of the mobile interface URLs, thanks! Also, I assume you are correct that there is currently no way to do this for desktop G+; I will mark your answer as correct for now. Hopefully Google will add support for this in the future...